# Track PID of process I just started in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
casperjs CMQ_scraper.js
Stop-Process -name phantomjs
```

I want to start a process (casperjs CMQ_scraper.js) and then immediately kill it.

CMQ_scraper.js shows up as phantomjs.exe in command line. however, I may have other phantomjs instances running that I don't want to kill. How can I save the PID of the new process so that I can later kill it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Start-Process` to create your process and use the `-PassThru` switch. That way you can save the return into a variable.

Then you can use that variable and pipe it into `Stop-Process`

```
$specificProcess = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru
$specificProcess | Stop-Process
```

[As Ansgar points out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) you can call the `.Kill()` method as well of `$specificProcess`

```
$specificProcess.Kill()
```

If you *really* needed the PID then you can get that off the `$specificProcess.ID`

Comment: Beat me to it. As an alternative to piping into `Stop-Process` you could also do `$specificProcess.Kill()`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Matt has his day!

Comment: Know how I could automatically hide the command prompt that appears?

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak Depending on the process and if it is willing to honor it you are looking at `-WindowStyle` or `-NoNewWindow`. [Have a look at technet for more info on those.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh849848.aspx)